# how to get the oracle database version from dump file

Tags: database, oracle, version, datapump

I have a oracle dump file. I want to know the version of the oracle db that the dump file used. e.g. if the dump file is used oracle 11g or oracle 12c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no direct way to get the **database version** directly from an exported dump file.

The database version should be known by the DBA/whoever did the export.

You could find the **export utility version** from the dump file or the export log though. However, *not necessarily* that the export utility version would be same as that of the database.

```
strings my_dump_file.dmp | head -n 5
```

For example, in **Unix/Linux**:

```
-sh-4.1$ strings expfull_DB.dmp|head -n 5
"SYS"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01"
x86_64/Linux 2.4.xx
PRIP
AL32UTF8
11.02.00.00.00
```

You can see the **export utility version** to be `11.02`.

Comment: windows version: `type expfull_DB.dmp | more`